# Unable to compare two dates in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I am struggling for comparing dates in MVC. I tried all the ways but still nothing went well. Seems to very strange.

This is my Datetime textbox bounded with JQuery calendar.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.dateofAction, ViewBag.filterdateTime as string, new { @id = "dateofAction", @placeholder = "Date Of Action", @class = "form-control datepicker validate[required, custom[date,future[min]]]", style = "width:80%;height:20px;" })
```

This is my Model field.

```
public DateTime? dateofAction { get; set; }
```

Finaly this is my query

```
upld_id = (from c in db.ts_upld_doc where (c.upld_ModifiedDateTime).Value.Year == datemodified.Year select c.upld_docid).ToArray();
```

I hit breakpoint and checked. I found values as below.

- `11/10/2016 12:00:00 AM` - User supplied date
- `2016-10-11 13:52:53.583` - Sql table(upld_ModifiedDateTime)

I tried in many ways like comparing only day,date,month,year but nothing worked for me. Can some expert tell me why I am having this issue? thank you very much.

Comment: Probably both the dates have to be in the same format.

Comment: That query seems strange to me. I can't check it, but shouldn't be something like `(from c in db.ts_upld_doc where (c.upld_ModifiedDateTime.Value.Year == datemodified.Year) select c.upld_docid).ToArray();`?

Comment: What are you trying to do - compare `DateTime` values for the same date (ignoring the time)?

Comment: Do either of the dates have double quotes around data indicating there are strings and not DateTime object?  Dates may not compare due to hours/minutes.  To truncate a DateTime to midnight use Date property.

Comment: Hi Stephen. I tried something like below...EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(c.upld_ModifiedDateTime)== dateofAction but no luck. This does not work so i went ahead and tried to compare date,month and year individually. even that is not worked. Really looks like very strange..

Comment: What is the type in your database for column `upld_ModifiedDateTime`? Is it a DateTime or is it a varchar that you are trying to treat as a datetime? If its the latter you need to correct your schema and already persisted data first.

Comment: public Nullable<System.DateTime> upld_ModifiedDateTime { get; set; }

Comment: Just curious. Did you try what i commented?

Comment: Are you sure your user supplied date's string value is `MM/dd/...` format and not `dd/MM/...`? That would actually make it 10 November instead of 11 October. You can look at the Month property on the DateTime instance to see.

Comment: user supplied date is in dd/MM/yyyy format. I am using jquery calender for textbox and iformat is as below.   Format: dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",

Comment: Thanks for all your responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the query to select the value between the start and end of the day

```
DateTime start = datemodified.Date;
DateTime end = start.AddDays(1);

upld_id = (from c in db.ts_upld_doc 
           where c.upld_ModifiedDateTime >= start && c.upld_ModifiedDateTime < end 
           select c.upld_docid).ToArray();
```

or

```
upld_id = db.ts_upld_doc
    .Where(c => where c.upld_ModifiedDateTime >= start && c.upld_ModifiedDateTime < end)
    .Select(c => c.upld_docid);
```

Comment: Thank you Stephen. Still my dates are not comparing.

Comment: What do you mean? If `datemodified` is `11/10/2016 12:00:00`, then `start` will be `11/10/2016 12:00:00` and `end` will be `12/10/2016 12:00:00` (`dd/MM/yyyy` format) so a record with `upld_ModifiedDateTime = 2016-10-11 13:52:53.583` **will** be returned

Comment: Correct I agree. It is not comparing.

Comment: Then there is something else you have not told us. And what is `datemodified` (the property in your question is `dateofAction`)

Comment: datemodified is the Datetime field I am taking from Textbox. dateofAction is the Model.

Comment: This answer works, as does the answer by Igor, so there is something you are not telling us about your data or the values you are passing in the query.

Comment: Even i am sure about your queries.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125414/discussion-between-niranjan-godbole-and-stephen-muecke).

Comment: Fixed. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

First remove time from upld_ModifiedDateTime and then use DateTime.Compare method to do the comparision as shown below:

```
upld_id = (from c in db.ts_upld_doc where
        DateTime.Compare(
            new DateTime(c.upld_ModifiedDateTime.Year, c.upld_ModifiedDateTime.Month, c.upld_ModifiedDateTime.Day))
        ,datemodified) == 0
      select c.upld_docid).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks you. Below error hits. Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using [DbFunctions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions(v=vs.113).aspx) with EF6.

```
var dateValue = datemodified.Date;

var upld_id = (
  from c in db.ts_upld_doc 
  where DbFunctions.TruncateTime(c.upld_ModifiedDateTime) == dateValue 
  select c.upld_docid).ToArray();
```

If you are using an older version of EF use [EntityFunctions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395596(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var dateValue = datemodified.Date;

var upld_id = (
  from c in db.ts_upld_doc 
  where EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(c.upld_ModifiedDateTime) == dateValue 
  select c.upld_docid).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is `datemodified` declared, and how does it get its value?
If `datemodified` is declared and set through your Action method in the Controller, then the *parameter name* you chose could be the problem.

So this will not work:

```
// MVC ignores Form field 'dateofAction' because it expects 'datemodified'.
[HttpPost]
ActionResult Index(DateTime datemodified) { ... }
```

Whereas this should work:

```
// MVC uses Form field 'dateofAction' to set parameter 'dateofAction'.
[HttpPost]
ActionResult Index(DateTime dateofAction) { ... }
```